# Where does Internet Explorer save the files which I have opened?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I opened an Excel file from Internet Explorer, worked on it for 2 hours and saved it. But now I can't find the file. The file was really important. Is there any way I can retrieve it? I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/q/258001/231678)

Comment: You can also look in Recent Items - go to the Start Menu, then click Recent Items, then right click your file and Open File Location. This will open the folder that it is saved in.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be in your Downloads folder. On the Start Menu, type `downloads` and the top result should be a folder called Downloads. Click on this to open it. The Excel workbook should be in this folder along with your other downloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE9 it's pretty simple. Click on the gear in the top right -> then download and then you should see where the files go. If you are using IE8 then it's more than likely in your Download folder in your personal directory. Even IE9 defaults to HOME/Downloads.

Beside all that you can try. Open  Windows Explorer, Click the search box in the top right and then pick datemodified. You should be able to search for all file modified on your windows box within the timeframe you choose. You don't have to type a name in, just pick a date and away it will go.

Happy Hunting!